# What is the difference between differencing a time series vs. differencing in ARIMA?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm very confused by these two methods. If I were to use the arima function in R and set d=2 would that be the same thing as differencing the original time series twice or would I be essentially differencing it an additional 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the arima function in R and set d = 2 that will be the same as differencing the original time series twice. From R documentation you can see in the arima specification d is the degree of differencing of the non-seasonal part. It means how many times you need to differentiate the ARIMA series for making the series stationary. By d = 2 you're telling the arima function to take the difference of the original data twice.
"order    A specification of the non-seasonal part of the ARIMA model: the three integer components (p, d, q) are the AR order, the degree of differencing, and the MA order."

Reference: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/arima